# How to maintain login session active even after refreshing page in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, commercetools

```html
signInMe() {
 
      this.$store.dispatch('setLoggedUser', true);
      this.$store.dispatch('setGenericAccessToken', response.data.access_token);

     
      this.errorMessage = "";
    }, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        this.errorMessage = error.response.data.message;
        this.isLoginFailed = true;
        this.emailFailureCount = this.emailFailureCount + 1;
       
      }
    }).catch(error => {})
},
```

```js
logout() {
  localStorage.clear();
  localStorage.setItem('userType', "G");
  this.$store.dispatch('setLoggedUser', false);
  this.$store.dispatch('setAccessToken', '');
  this.$router.push('/')
  this.registeredUser = false;
},
```

```html
<div class="myprofileroute" @click="logout">Logout</div>
```

After logging in successfully with my login credentials, I am able to redirect to some page, and if I click on logout, I am successfully logging out. The issue is even after login without clicking on Logout button, even if I refresh my page it is getting logged out.

Comment: What kind of an authentication system are you using? JWT?

Comment: @Areg using the CommerceTool

Comment: How does your login method look?

Comment: @egx i have shared my login method code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the access token in your local/session storage, and then on each page load check whether it exists or not.

```
async login(){
  try{
    const userData = await axios.post('yourapi');
    const token = userData.access_token;
    localStorage.setItem('userData', userData);
    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', token);
    this.$router.push('/dashboard');
  }catch(err){
     //Handle errors
  }
}
```

Then maybe on your main layout or on Vue instance

```
mounted(){
  const userData = localStorage.getItem('userData');
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
  localStorage.setItem('userType', "G");
  this.$store.dispatch('setLoggedUser', userData);
  this.$store.dispatch('setAccessToken', accessToken);
}
```

Comment: @taneerudhanunjay i see you have already set the new logic in login function, all you need to do now is check on every refresh if that token exists and verify it